# GParted, shrink lvm partition to give boot more space

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition, gparted

I keep having issues due to my boot drive running out of space. It fills up as soon as I try to sort out packages with apt-get upgrade, or if for any other reason dependencies try to be resolved or similar. And when I clear it out often I break something I'm working on. So as it has inevitably filled up again causing me issues I want to give it some more space.

GParted is showing my lvm partition as having only 44MiB of unused space. `df` shows I'm only using 33% of the total space. Is there any way I can re-organise this partition so that I can free up some space to give to /boot? If not, should I grab another drive and extend the boot partition?

[image]
[image]

`ll /boot`

[image]

Comment: that boot partition isn't small - what's on it? in some distros you have to manually uninstall old kernels, if you don't do that, no size will ever be enough in the long run

Comment: Per @frostschutz comment/query, you probably need to clean up old kernel images or something similar. As for the LVM question, please update the question with details on the logical volumes on /dev/sda5. Output from `df -hTP` and `lsblk` is probably sufficient.

Comment: @0xSheepdog I've ran the commands and added the screenshot of the results to the post

Comment: @frostschutz lots of different vm bits and bobs, moving over to docker soon I hope. I added a screenshot to the post

Comment: @Shard you don't keep "vm bits and bobs" on the hosts' /boot partition. That looks very much like old kernels to me, there's even still 4.4 kernels when you're already using 4.15 and you only need the very latest one (or two) of those.

Comment: perhaps try https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: @frostschutz how come it has filled back up in 2 months? And last time I cleared it out it broke all of my virtual machines so I'm cautious to do that again, and that does indicate to me that they're in use. Sorry if this is dense of me

Comment: Another note, in-case this is ever answered. sudo apt-get install package sometimes requires files from the boot drive which I don't have, and since I have no space it fails to install. Example `sudo apt-get install espeak` results in: The following packages have unmet dependencies. linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed or linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed"

Comment: @frostschutz I'm unable to follow any of the steps in the linked question due to unmet dependencies which require different linux images in /boot (which of course is full). Can I just go and rm stuff which doesn't match uname -r in /boot? 

I don't use vm's at all any more (moved completely over to docker) so I've come back to trying to clear out /boot

Comment: For anyone else looking at the comment above, I just nuked everything but my current kernel with rm -rf so I could get the software I needed to get a fresh ubuntu install on a new ssd.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing boot (which I suspected would be the only suggestion) obviously didn't work for me as as soon as I try to do anything with my packages it generates a ton more stuff and fills it back up.

I suspect the reason I couldn't shrink sda5 was due to the partition table being mbr rather than gpt, resolving that may fix this for others. For me it seems something was majorly fucked up with my system so I bought a new ssd and I'm in the process of installing a new distro to that before transferring over my old files.

I won't mark this as an accepted answer, because it isn't an acceptable answer. But this may help someone so here you go.